# Present ModalView from LeftSideView Controller in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I implemented a split view in my project. My leftside view contain a tableview & a button.

Onclick of that bitton, i present the modalview.

It works fine in Landscape Mode,But for the portrait mode, the view is appear as same as leftside frame view Rather than on full screen.

it also works fine for ios6 in Landscape & portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register notification in your detail view controller and then from root just post notification when you need modal view controller to be presented.

Let's assume that you are using ARC. In your split controller you have left view controller called root controller and right called detail controller.

In your detail controller you will need to implement code to register and remove notification.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(displayModalController) name:@"DisplayModalControllerNotification" object:nil];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)displayModalController {

    UIViewController *myController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:^{
        // code to be executed after completition
    }];
}
```

Now with this code in place in your root controller you will simply call it whenever you need it with this line of code:

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DisplayModalControllerNotification" object:nil];
```

This is basic sample, modify by your needs, for example if you need to send some object with notification to be delivered to your modal view controller on init, etc.

Comment: thanks for replay! I tried your code but crashed  & gave following error  ;       "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController _presentPopoverBySlidingIn:fromEdge:ofView:animated:stateOnly:notifyDelegate:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'"

Comment: Hmm that's strange because I didn't used UIPopOverController anywhere so it must be somewhere in your code.